# Where is load-opportunities and diagnostics in lighthouse api?

Tags: javascript, lighthouse

I am showing website audits in my website using google lighthouse npm. I am getting the response.
But where can I find `load-opportunities` and `diagnostics` ? I am not able to find these two groups in whole respose

I have seen the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636725/pagespeed-insights-api-v5), according to the first answer I should be able to find load-opportunities and diagnostics in auditRefs group. But there are no grops like these two. I only can see metrics, budget hidden group.

According to another answer I can find opportunities in `type=opportunities` which I found, but where can I find diagnostics ? There is no type like `diagnostics`?
can anyone help me in that ?

The response is about of 40k lines so can not attach it

Answer (score -1):

To view the "Load opportunities" and "Diagnostics" categories in a Lighthouse report, you can do the following:

Run a Lighthouse audit for your website using a tool that supports these categories, such as the Lighthouse Chrome extension or the Lighthouse CLI.
After the audit is complete, open the Lighthouse report in your web browser or the CLI output.
Look for the "Load opportunities" and "Diagnostics" categories in the report. These categories are typically listed alongside other categories like "Performance", "Accessibility", "Best Practices", and "SEO".
Click on each category to view the specific opportunities and diagnostics that were identified by Lighthouse.
If you are still unable to find the "Load opportunities" and "Diagnostics" categories in your Lighthouse report, it is possible that they were not included in the audit options that were selected. In that case, you may need to run a new audit with the desired categories selected.